# “To sit waiting” vs. “to be sitting waiting”

Tags: progressive-aspect

- I'm sitting waiting for a bus.
- I sit waiting for a bus.

There is the situation that I'm sitting on a bench and I'm waiting for a bus in a bus station.

If I want to tell my friend that by a phone. I say "I sit waiting for a bus." It is right?

Somewhere, I have heard "I'm sitting waiting for a bus" means that I'm sitting up and down (it doesn't mean an exercise)  while waiting a bus, as a bus has arrived.
 Therefore Someone tell me you would use I sit waiting for a bus.

Simply, I think I'm sitting + I'm waiting = I'm sitting waiting.

How are the two sentences different?

also

- I sitting  waiting for a bus.
- I sitting and waiting for a bus.

differ?

Comment: I'm curious; where did you hear that "I'm sitting waiting for the bus." means "I'm sitting up and down waiting for the bus."?  There's "I'm sitting up." which implies "I was previously laying down", and there's "I'm sitting down." which implies "I was previously standing".  I've never heard those to be implied in "I'm sitting [verb]ing...".

Comment: What you were told about *to be sitting* implying repeated performing the action of adopting a seated position is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the `am` is required, as it shows that you are in the process of sitting and waiting for the bus.

> I am sitting, waiting for the bus

The sentence is made up of two clauses:

> *I am sitting*, **waiting for the bus**

or

> *I am sitting* and **waiting for the bus**

Both are equally acceptable as it is a matter of connecting two seperate clauses, either by means of a `,` or an `and`.

On the matter of your use of

> I sit waiting for a bus

it is not incorrect, *per se*, but it wouldn't be used by a native speaker; it is passive, and one expects a `while` after it, and for it to be written not spoken. Instead I would suggest:

> I'm waiting for the bus

simply for authenticity.

Comment: Great answer. I'd just like to add, the two sentences could also be joined with an adverb or prepositional phrase, too, such as: _"I'm sitting **here** waiting for a bus_", or _"I'm sitting **on a bench** waiting for a bus_."

Comment: @J.R. - but why "I sit waiting for a bus" is passive?