# to be sitting vs to sit

Tags: infinitives

Could you please explain why the infinitive that means "to be in a position in which the upper body is upright and the legs (especially the upper legs) are supported by some object" is **to be sitting** but not just **to sit**.  What is the difference between both infinitives?

Comment: Why do you think there's a difference?

Comment: When we use **to sit** as a to-infinitive, it expresses exactly the meaning you described. "*[As by the dead we love **to sit**, become so wondrous dear](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/As_by_the_dead_we_love_to_sit,)*.."

Comment: Related: **[to sit waiting vs. to be sitting waiting](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32459/to-sit-waiting-vs-to-be-sitting-waiting)**

Answer (score 3):

"To sit" is the infinitive, "To be sitting" is actually the present continuous tense, which is generally used to refer to the act of remaining seated. "To sit" is in the present simple, and it refers to the act of sitting down.

"I sit on the chair" sounds like you're talking about the act of sitting down, while "I am sitting on the chair" unambiguously refers to the fact that you are currently on the chair.

Comment: Actually, "I sit on the chair" sounds to me like you're sitting on there chair. Other than that, though, I like this answer.

Comment: @J.R. - if Natalia's question is about the lexical aspect differences between "I sit on the chair" / "I am sitting on the char", then telling that "sit" denotes only the action of assuming a sitting position would be wrong, IMHO.

Comment: @CopperK - Oh, I agree. That "only" part you refer to is the key to the mystery. That said, I don't agree with this way this is worded: _"I sit on the chair" sounds like you're talking about the act of sitting down_ – it doesn't sound right to me. Moreover, "I am sitting on the chair" could mean that I'm in the act of sitting down, and it's not as "unambiguous" as this answer claims. In short, I think this is on the right track, but it needs some polishing.